# Can smart contract code query the block chain?

Tags: smart-contract

A EOS C++ smart contract can have code that query and iterate through the blockchain, to get the actions and transactions and related data?

In eos.js you can do `eos.getActions(accountName)` but inside smart contract in c++ i don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contracts may query tables, but not arbitrary transactions. e.g. a contract can get user balances by querying token tables.